# Exporting to excel programmatically from button click

Tags: c#, excel

I am having some trouble with code I'm trying to use to export some data to excel through a button click. I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

In my code, I have an `ExcelExport` class which contains the following code

```
 class ExcelExport
    {
        DirectoryInfo outputDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\SampleApp");
        /// <summary>
        /// ExcelExport simply creates a new workbook from scratch.
        /// The workbook contains one worksheet with a simple invertory list
        /// </summary>
        public static string RunSample1(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
        {

            if (!outputDir.Exists) throw new Exception("outputDir does not exist!");
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample1.xlsx");
            if (newFile.Exists)
            {
                newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
                newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample1.xlsx");
            }
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {
                // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Inventory");
                //Add the headers
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Product";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Quantity";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Price";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Value";

                //Add some items...
                worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 12001;
                worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Nails";
                worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 37;
                worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 3.99;

                worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value = 12002;
                worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "Hammer";
                worksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 5;
                worksheet.Cells["D3"].Value = 12.10;

                worksheet.Cells["A4"].Value = 12003;
                worksheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "Saw";
                worksheet.Cells["C4"].Value = 12;
                worksheet.Cells["D4"].Value = 15.37;

                //Add a formula for the value-column
                worksheet.Cells["E2:E4"].Formula = "C2*D2";

                //Ok now format the values;
                using (var range = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 5])
                {
                    range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.DarkBlue);
                    range.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
                }

                worksheet.Cells["A5:E5"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                worksheet.Cells["A5:E5"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

                worksheet.Cells[5, 3, 5, 5].Formula = string.Format("SUBTOTAL(9,{0})", new ExcelAddress(2, 3, 4, 3).Address);
                worksheet.Cells["C2:C5"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";
                worksheet.Cells["D2:E5"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";

                //Create an autofilter for the range
                worksheet.Cells["A1:E4"].AutoFilter = true;

                worksheet.Cells["A2:A4"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";   //Format as text

                //There is actually no need to calculate, Excel will do it for you, but in some cases it might be useful. 
                //For example if you link to this workbook from another workbook or you will open the workbook in a program that hasn't a calculation engine or 
                //you want to use the result of a formula in your program.
                worksheet.Calculate();

                worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns(0);  //Autofit columns for all cells

                // lets set the header text 
                worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddHeader.CenteredText = "&24&U&\"Arial,Regular Bold\" Inventory";
                // add the page number to the footer plus the total number of pages
                worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.RightAlignedText =
                    string.Format("Page {0} of {1}", ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber, ExcelHeaderFooter.NumberOfPages);
                // add the sheet name to the footer
                worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.CenteredText = ExcelHeaderFooter.SheetName;
                // add the file path to the footer
                worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.LeftAlignedText = ExcelHeaderFooter.FilePath + ExcelHeaderFooter.FileName;

                worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatRows = worksheet.Cells["1:2"];
                worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatColumns = worksheet.Cells["A:G"];

                // Change the sheet view to show it in page layout mode
                worksheet.View.PageLayoutView = true;

                // set some document properties
                package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Invertory";
                package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Jan Källman";
                package.Workbook.Properties.Comments = "This sample demonstrates how to create an Excel 2007 workbook using EPPlus";

                // set some extended property values
                package.Workbook.Properties.Company = "AdventureWorks Inc.";

                // set some custom property values
                package.Workbook.Properties.SetCustomPropertyValue("Checked by", "Jan Källman");
                package.Workbook.Properties.SetCustomPropertyValue("AssemblyName", "EPPlus");
                // save our new workbook and we are done!
                package.Save();

            }

            return newFile.FullName;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to execute this code upon a button click event in my application. This is the code I am using for that:

```
 ExcelExport.RunSample1(DirectoryInfo.outputDir);
```

The application is rejecting the button code stating that "System.IO.DirectoryInfo does not contain a definition for outPutDir"

I can't for the life of me see what I've done wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you added 'using System.IO;' to your namespaces?

Comment: `DirectoryInfo` is a class, you need to pass an instance of it to your method, you are trying to access a static property/field on the class that does not exist and pass that to your method.

Comment: Should it be ExcelExport.RunSample1(outputDir);  ?

Comment: But see I tried that then I receive an error that outputDir is not available in the current context. Its behaving really oddly IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the 'DirectoryInfo.' part of the method call. Should just be

```
ExcelExport.RunSample1(outputDir);
```

Comment: But see I tried that then I receive an error that outputDir is not available in the current context. Its behaving really oddly IMO

Comment: I will open another question for this context issue. Thank you all for clearing that up!